# Impossible to convert between the formats supported by the filter '...' - Error reinitializing filters

Tags: ffmpeg, gpu

I am using this ffmpeg command(values removed for simplicity)

```
ffmpeg -hwaccel cuvid -c:v h264_cuvid -y -ss 1 -i "FILE0001.MOV" -ss 0 -i "GOPR0621.MP4" -filter_complex 
[0:v][1:v]
  midequalizer
[al];
[al]
  yadif
  lenscorrection
  scale
[vl];
[1:v]
  lenscorrection
  scale
[vr];
[vl][vr]
  hstack=shortest=1 
-an -c:v h264_nvenc -preset slow "output.mp4"
```

on a machine with a cuda graphics card.

I get

```
ffmpeg version N-90979-g08032331ac Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7.3.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth
  libavutil      56. 18.100 / 56. 18.100
  libavcodec     58. 19.100 / 58. 19.100
  libavformat    58. 13.101 / 58. 13.101
  libavdevice    58.  4.100 / 58.  4.100
  libavfilter     7. 21.100 /  7. 21.100
  libswscale      5.  2.100 /  5.  2.100
  libswresample   3.  2.100 /  3.  2.100
  libpostproc    55.  2.100 / 55.  2.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00000254a8afc0c0] st: 0 edit list: 1 Missing key frame while searching for timestamp: 6006
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00000254a8afc0c0] st: 0 edit list 1 Cannot find an index entry before timestamp: 6006.
....
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (h264_cuvid) -> midequalizer:in0
  Stream #1:0 (h264) -> midequalizer:in1
  Stream #1:0 (h264) -> lenscorrection
  hstack -> Stream #0:0 (h264_nvenc)
  
Impossible to convert between the formats supported by the filter 'graph 0 input from stream 0:0' and the filter 'auto_scaler_0'
Error reinitializing filters!
```

The same command without CUDA works, ie

```
ffmpeg -y -ss 1 -i "FILE0001.MOV" -ss 0 -i "GOPR0621.MP4" -filter_complex 
[0:v][1:v]
  midequalizer
[al];
[al]
  yadif
  lenscorrection
  scale
[vl];
[1:v]
  lenscorrection
  scale
[vr];
[vl][vr]
  hstack=shortest=1 
-an "output.mp4"
```

How do I make it work on a Windows 10 machine with cuda?

Answer (score 8):

solution as of 2020: you need to pass `hwupload_cuda` along with the filter to explicitly tell FFmpeg what to do.

So your command should look like this:

```
ffmpeg -hwaccel cuvid -c:v h264_cuvid -vsync 0 -y -i input.mp4 -vf "hwupload_cuda,scale_npp=w=1280:h=-2" -c:v h264_nvenc ...
```

Detail about this issue is described here: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/5587

Comment: instead cuvid use `-hwaccel nvdec -hwaccel_output_format cuda` he is more omnivorous

Comment: That gives `No such filter: 'scale_npp'` for me.

Comment: Try `scale_cuda` instead of `scale_npp`. The latter apparently requires the CUDA SDK and a non-free license, so Gyan does not include it in his [ffmpeg binaries for Windows](https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/) ([details](https://www.reddit.com/r/ffmpeg/comments/euiwtv/comment/fjwojvb/)).

Answer (score 1):

Don't have a CUDA device to test with, but it should be

```
ffmpeg -hwaccel cuvid -c:v h264_cuvid -y -ss 1 -i "FILE0001.MOV" -ss 0 -i "GOPR0621.MP4" -filter_complex 
[0:v]hwdownload,format=nv12,format=yuv420p[0v];
[0v][1:v]
  midequalizer
[al];
[al]
  yadif
  lenscorrection
  scale
[vl];
[1:v]
  lenscorrection
  scale
[vr];
[vl][vr]
  hstack=shortest=1 
-an -c:v h264_nvenc -preset slow "output.mp4"
```

Comment: When decoding in hardware, and then using software filters like midequalizer, the frames have to transferred to system RAM. The GPU supports a limited number of pixel formats and ffmpeg does not yet support pixel format auto conversion from a GPU format to s/w formats.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use cuvid, it is not better decoder in 2020. Just allow ffmpeg to choose the decoder by himself. You need specifie that you are want to use hardware acceleration.

Your piplene should looks like:

```
ffmpeg -hwaccel nvdec -hwaccel_device 0 -hwaccel_output_format cuda -i input_file.mp4 -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -c:v:0 h264_nvenc -b:v:0 650000 -filter:v:0 scale_npp=-2:360:interp_algo=super,hwdownload,format=nv12 -c:a:0 aac -b:a:0 96000 -ac:a:0 2 -max_muxing_queue_size 9999 -movflags +faststart -f mp4 /home/uploads/tmp.mp4
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work by limiting the number of threads used for encoding.

"-threads 9" and lower worked, "-threads 10" or above failed with the error.

Comment: I had a different command, with `-hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda` and used `scale_cuda` filter but the same error... And surprisingly it worked for me! :O It was `-threads 12` for me tho (13+ fails, I have a 16 threads on my cpu).

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue on ubuntu 22.04 (while it was working fine on win10)

For me adding "-extra_hw_frames 30" fixed the problem, with warnings though

ex:

```
ffmpeg -hwaccel nvdec -hwaccel_output_format cuda -extra_hw_frames 10 -i myvideo.mp4 -c:a copy -c:v h264_nvenc -rc vbr -profile:v high -preset p6 -tune hq -pix_fmt yuv420p -s 1024x576 -y -f mp4 video.mp4
```

source: https://github.com/HaveAGitGat/Tdarr/issues/820